# C# Refactor: Inverting default value of boolean parameter

Tags: c#, parameters, boolean, refactoring

if I have a method like this:

```
public void Foo(object arg1, object arg2, bool flag = false);
```

Is there any refactoring (built-in, R# or other) to flip that default value of the "flag" parameter to true, fixing all usages automatically (removing the "false" from all calls that call with "false", and adding "true" to all others)?

Comment: So far i know, there is no way to do something like this. Visual Studio 2015 allows you to search and replace with regex. But i think this is dangerous and will change much more code then you would expect.

Comment: Can I ask why you would need to change the default value? Is it just for semtantics?

Comment: Hey, of course you can ask. It's an internal API that was designed the wrong way around, so to speak. So the default value given is used in far less occurances than the inverted case. I know optional parameters are evil, but *if* used, they should represent the most-often used case, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think Visual Studio nor ReSharper can invert the default value of a boolean parameter.

You can however invert all usages of the parameter within the method.
With ReSharper you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (or right-click the declared boolean and press `Refactor this`), and then select [Invert Boolean](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.1/Refactorings_Invert_Boolean.html) in the menu. This will open a dialogue which lets you choose a new name, and then ReSharper will invert all usages of the boolean.

[image: Screenshot of the refactor menu.]

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work for method parameters / arguments, does it? Maybe my R# version is too old?

Comment: @Dr.TimdosSantos It works in the newest version ReSharper at least. I am trying to figure out which version introduced this feature.

Comment: @Dr.TimdosSantos Sorry, I didn't read the question properly. It seems that ReSharper does not handle the default value in the parameter declaration.